# Checking error for empty csv files in python using data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several csv files in a directory of folders and subfolders. All the csv files have headers and time stamp as 1st column, whether time series data is present or not. I want to read all the csv files and should return status as empty if no data is present.

When I used `df.empty` function to check, it returns False even there is no data (the file has only header row and 1st column with time stamp).

**The code I used is:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("D://sirifort_with_data.csv", index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv("D://sirifort_without_data.csv", index_col=0)
print(df1.empty)
print(df2.empty)
print(df2)
```

The result is:
False
False
PM2.5(ug/m3)  PM10(ug/m3)  ...  NOx(ppb)  NH3(ug/m3)
Time_Stamp                                  ...
26/02/2022 0:00           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 0:15           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 0:30           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 0:45           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 1:00           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 1:15           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 1:30           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 1:45           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 2:00           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 2:15           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 2:30           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN
26/02/2022 2:45           NaN          NaN  ...       NaN         NaN

[12 rows x 6 columns]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sum of one of the columns. in the case of empty df it is zero.

```
def col_check(col):
   if df[col].sum()!=0:
       return 1

for col in df.columns:
   if col_check(col):
       print('not empty')
       break
```

The documentation clearly indicates:

> If we only have NaNs in our DataFrame, it is not considered empty! We
> will need to drop the NaNs to make the DataFrame empty:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.nan]})
df.empty
False
```

and then suggests:

```
df.dropna().empty
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the column I used to sum up, is empty and other column may have data, in that case, the result will be wrong.

Comment: So, put it in a loop to check all the columns and then returns 1 if and only if the len of all is zero.

Comment: I thought of the same, but want to know why df.empty function not working

Comment: I think it is because of the index.

Comment: From documentation:  True if Series/DataFrame is entirely empty (no items), meaning any of the axes are of length 0.

Comment: df = df_input_csv.dropna(how='all')   solved my problem. Thank you